# Call jquery fuction on form submit in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using this code to request new user to change his password on first login. So here is my form which opens in a popup after first login:

```
<div class="modal" id="change-password-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" style="top:20%">
            <div class="modal-content content-align">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title text-center modal-title-col">Change your password</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="change-password" class="ns-form half-width" method="post" action="/profile/changepassword">
                  <?php if(empty($_POST) || isset($exc)): ?>
                  <label>
                    <input class="input-box" type="password" name="curr_pwd" required="required" maxlength="64" placeholder="Current Password" required="required" />
                    <?php if(isset($exc) && $exc->getCode() == eInfo::INVALID_CREDENTIALS): ?>
                      <span class="error msg-block bottom">
                        <?php echo stripslashes($exc->getMessage()); ?>
                      </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    <input class="input-box" type="password" name="new_pwd" required="required" maxlength="64" placeholder="New Password" />
                      <?php if(isset($exc) && $exc->getCode() == eInfo::INVALID_PASSWORD): ?>
                        <span class="error msg-block bottom">
                          <?php echo stripslashes($exc->getMessage()); ?>
                        </span>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    <input class="input-box" type="password" name="retype_pwd"
                           required="required" maxlength="64" placeholder="Re-type Password" />
                  </label>
                  <center> <input type="submit" value="Change" class="change-button" id="change-button" /> </center>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </form>
                <?php if(!empty($_POST) && !isset($exc) && isset($message)): ?>
                    <br/>
                    <strong><?php echo $message; ?></strong>
                    <br/>
                    <center><a href="/">Go home</a></center>
                <?php endif; ?>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

When i click on submit function it takes me to profile/changepassword which i have written in action. I want my form to submit in the popup only not to redirect to other page.

profile/changepassword function in controller

```
public function changepassword() {
        User::authenticate();
        $this->log->debug("Inside " . __METHOD__ . "()...");

        $this->template->title = 'ChangePassword - '.TITLE_SUFFIX;

        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            try {
                $allowed = array('curr_pwd', 'new_pwd', 'retype_pwd');
                if($allowed != array_keys($_POST)) {
                    loadException('InvalidFormSubmissionException');
                    throw new \InvalidFormSubmissionException();
                }

                User::validatePassword($_POST['new_pwd']);

                if($_POST['new_pwd'] !== $_POST['retype_pwd'])
                    throw new model\exceptions\user\InvalidPasswordException('Passwords do not match!');

                if($_POST['curr_pwd'] === $_POST['new_pwd'])
                    throw new model\exceptions\user\InvalidPasswordException('Current password and new password should not be same!');

                $userService = new model\UserService();
                if(!($user = $userService->verifyPasswordForUser($_SESSION['userId'], $_POST['curr_pwd']))) {
                    loadException('user/InvalidCredentialsException');
                    throw new model\exceptions\user\InvalidCredentialsException('Wrong password!');
                }
                /*var $user User */
                $user->setPassword(md5($_POST['new_pwd']));
                $user->getPwdUpdated(1);
                $_SESSION['pwd_updated']=1;
                $userService->update($user);
                $this->template->message = 'Your password has been changed.';
            } catch(model\exceptions\user\InvalidCredentialsException $e) {
                $this->log->debug($e->getMessage());
                $this->template->exc =$e;
            } catch (\InvalidFormSubmissionException $e) {
                $this->log->debug($e->getMessage());
                $this->template->exc = $e;
            } catch(model\exceptions\user\InvalidPasswordException $e) {
                $this->log->debug($e->getMessage());
                $this->template->exc = $e;
            } catch(\Exception $e) {
                $this->log->debug($e->getMessage());
                $this->template->exc = $e;
            }
        }
        $this->log->debug("Peak memory usage in " . __METHOD__ . " = " . (memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE) / 1024) . " KB");
        $this->template->setLayout('profile');
        $this->template->show();
    }
```

It's a basic little question but i don't know how to do it.THANKS!

Comment: if you want to avoid redirection use **AJAX**

Answer (score 0):

Either move the code in changepassword to the page your form is in, so that you can send the form to its own page and therefore no redirection needed, or you'll have to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).